# createjs dynamic text over lapping

Tags: javascript, createjs

i am using flash cc createjs export. i am embedded flash font as well . but it did not fix the issue . 
i have attached the link here . just click the rectangle . it will create 10 
if you click again it will be 20 . but 20 overlaps 10 . 10 does not goes away.
http://graphicscoder.org/stackover/score/scoring.html

```
/* js 
var score=0;


this.movieClip_1.addEventListener('click', fl_MouseOverHandler_2);

function fl_MouseOverHandler_2(e)
{
    text1 = new createjs.Text("LIVES: " + score, "40px Arial");
text1.textAlign = 'right';
text1.y = 30;
text1.x = stage.canvas.width - 10;
stage.addChild(text1);
    score=score+10;
  text1.text=String(score);


}

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click the button, you are adding a new Text. If you want to just change the number:

1. Create the text once initially
2. Update the value on click

Example:

```
/* js 
var score=0;

this.movieClip_1.addEventListener('click', fl_MouseOverHandler_2);

// Moved out of the mouse handler
text1 = new createjs.Text("LIVES: " + score, "40px Arial");
text1.textAlign = 'right';
text1.y = 30;
text1.x = stage.canvas.width - 10;
stage.addChild(text1);

function fl_MouseOverHandler_2(e)
{
    score=score+10;
    text1.text=String(score);
}
*/
```